# Can I use simple present tense instead of past tense for recent events?

Tags: grammar, tenses, present-tense, simple-past

So, is this sentence can be use

`I am his teammate last match.` (but we are not teammates this match now )

instead of

`I was his teammate last match`

If the last match've just ended recently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really. The phrase "last match" locates the statement in the past, so the past tense "was" should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Historic Present
eg "Last Saturday, I arrive at midday to collect the deliveries and he's fast asleep! So I creep up close and shout ..."